# IQueryable doesn't allow ThenBy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, sorting

I'm trying to sort an IQueryable by multiple columns and many StackOverflow answers seem to indicate I should be able to do an OrderBy for the Primary sort and then a ThenBy for additional sorts. The OrderBy is fine but it's not allowing me to use ThenBy. It doesn't compile. I don't get why...

```
IQueryable<vMyView> contacts = db.vMyView;

var orderExpressions = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<vCRMAllContact, object>>>()
    {
         {"LastName", x => x.LastName},
         {"FirstName", x => x.FirstName},
         {"Email", x => x.Email},
         {"Telephone1", x => x.Telephone1}
     };

contacts = contacts.OrderBy(orderExpressions[sortExpression], ascending).ThenBy(orderExpressions["FirstName"]).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

Comment: How do you know it is not allowing `ThenBy`?

Comment: Which `.ThenBy()` is giving you an error? You have two in your example.

Comment: OrderBy actually returns IOrderedEnumerable. Maybe you can do AsQueryable() on that. The OrderBy implementation is pretty interesting in Linq, especially with ThenBy composition.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing 2 instances of ThenBy... the first one was an attempted work around that I forgot to cleanup. Getting rid of the first OrderBy and the ascending parameters in the 2nd statement resolved it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example is correct and absolutely should work:

```
var contacts = db.vMyView.OrderBy(c => c.LastName).ThenBy(c => c.FirstName);
// not sure why you need to reorder. Which could distort previous sorting
contacts = contacts.OrderBy(orderExpressions[sortExpression]).ThenBy(orderExpressions["FirstName"]);
```

Something looks off in your second example. `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` are already ascending there's no need for the additional parameter. There are alternatives for descending which are suffixed appropriately: `OrderByDescending` and `ThenByDescending`.